# Loading Data Into Peoplesoft DataBase with ExceltoCi

Tags: python, excel, vba, talend

I have been tasked with building an `ETL job` that takes financial `csv` data from an asset management program, transforms and delivers to our `PeopleSoft Financial system`.

I am using `Talend` and also writing some `python` scripts. This program will run once a week. The `PeopleSoft` team insists on using this "`Excel to Ci`" excel xlsm file which is an excel workbook with macros and `VBA` code. This thing is a nightmare to work with and isn't supported by Talend or fully compatible with python `openpyxl` package.

Is there a better way to push (`csv`) data into a `PeopleSoft` database while executing this supposed business logic?

Answer (score 1):

PeopleTools Integration Broker allows you to create web services that can invoke a CI. Then you could invoke the service using Python.

https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E41633_01/pt853pbh1/eng/pt/tibr/concept_UnderstandingCreatingComponentInterface-BasedServices-076354.html

Another alternative is to develop an App Engine program to read in the csv file and invoke the CI that way using PeopleCode.

Comment: Thanks that is really helpful, I decided to go for a quick fix for the time being and Implemented a PowerShell script into my Talend job as the Interop.Excel module can handle .xlsm without corrupting the VBA code (although appending rows is very slow)